# How to bind and change dynamic component input in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic component an app component. I am dynamically compile the dynamic component and add to app component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic',
  template: `<p>Dynamic Component {{ index }}</p>`
})
export class DynamicComponent {

  @Input() index: number;

}
```

And app component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  counter = 1;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);

    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);

    componentRef.instance.index = this.counter++;
  }

  add(){
    this.counter++;
  }

}
```

But after start the applicaiton, I am increasing the `counter`. But it does not change in dynamic component. Why?

Comment: counter variable is a primitive type and hence only the copy of the value is passed to the dynamic component. So if you increment the counter, you have to manually assign the new value to dynamic component instance fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't pass a counter by reference so you can do :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  counter = 1;
  componentRef: DynamicComponent;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);

    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);

    this.componentRef.instance.index = this.counter++;
  }

  add(){
    this.componentRef.instance.index = this.counter++;
  }

}
```

Maybe this can work if you can tell me ;)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  counter = 1;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);

    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);

    componentRef.instance.index = this.counter;
  }

  add(){
    this.counter++;
  }

}
```